# RecyclerView not scrolling with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm making a chat application that uses Firebase as a backend, but I'm having trouble getting the RecyclerView to scroll to the bottom of the list.  I have a chatActivity that has the following methods:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        Id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("matchId");
        Pic = findViewById(R.id.displayImageMessages);
        thoughtButton = findViewById(R.id.messageThought);

        //SET MENU
        menuButton = findViewById(R.id.messageMenu);
        menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                optionMenu = new PopupMenu(ChatActivity.this,menuButton);
                optionMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu2,optionMenu.getMenu());
                optionMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.one){
                            backtoMain();
                            return true;
                        }
                        else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.two){

                            return true;
                        }
                        else if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.three){
                            FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                            auth.signOut();
                            backtoMenu();
                            return true;
                        }
                        else{
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                });
                optionMenu.show();
            }
        });

       Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
        //LOAD  PICTURE
        URI = getIntent().getExtras().getString("displayPic");
        Glide.with(this).load(URI).thumbnail(0.4f).into(Pic);
        //RETRIEVE CHAT
        currentUserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        databaseUser  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(currentUserID).child("connections").child(Id).child("ChatId");
        databaseChat  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chat");
        getChatId();
        mSendEditText = findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        mSendButton = findViewById(R.id.send);
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendMessage();
            }
        });
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.ChatRecycler);
        mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ChatActivity.this);
        mChatLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mChatLayoutManager);
        mChatAdapter = new ChatViewAdapter(getDataSetChat(),ChatActivity.this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mChatAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(20));



    }
```

and

```
  private void getChatId() {
        databaseUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    chatId = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                    databaseChat = databaseChat.child(chatId);
                    getChatMessages();
                    linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(resultsChat.size(),0);
                    Log.d("messageTAG",String.valueOf(mChatAdapter.getItemCount()));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

and

```
 private void getChatMessages() {

        databaseChat.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    String message = null;
                    String createdbyuser = null;
                    long timestamp = 0;
                    if (dataSnapshot.child("text").getValue()!=null){
                        message = dataSnapshot.child("text").getValue().toString();
                    }
                    if (dataSnapshot.child("createdBy").getValue()!=null){
                        createdbyuser = dataSnapshot.child("createdBy").getValue().toString();
                    }
                    if (dataSnapshot.child("timestamp").getValue()!=null){
                        timestamp = Long.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("timestamp").getValue().toString());
                    }
                    if (message!=null&&createdbyuser!=null){
                        Boolean currentUserBoolean = false;
                        if (createdbyuser.equals(currentUserID)){
                            currentUserBoolean = true;
                        }

                        ChatObject newMessage = new ChatObject(message,currentUserBoolean,timestamp);
                        resultsChat.add(newMessage);
                        mChatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    //SETS VISABILITY OF THOUGHTS BUTTON IF CHAT SIZE IS ABOVE 10
                    if(resultsChat.size() > 10){
                        thoughtButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                }

            }
```

I've tried various layoutManager.ScrollToPosition or adapter.ScrollToPosition etc, but I'd appreciate any thoughts you have on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(resultsChat.size() - 1);
```

In `databaseChat.addChildEventListener()`

Like this :

```
ChatObject newMessage = new ChatObject(message,currentUserBoolean,timestamp);
resultsChat.add(newMessage);
mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(resultsChat.size() - 1); //here
mChatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: in which method?

Comment: getChatId() obviously

Comment: you say obviously but resultChat doesn't maintain it's size value when it gets to getChatID() which means when you call scrollToPosition it doesn't work.  i've tried manually putting an Int in there and that doesn't work either.

Comment: still not getting a scroll.... This time the list size is holding true but it's not scrolling down still. I've tried versions of LayoutManager  as well...

Comment: Can't say why it did'nt but it should work. https://github.com/thaleslima/firebase-chat-sample here is the reference u can take.

Comment: Ok so i've found the problem and your answer was correct. It seems there was a conflict between NestedScrollView and RecyclerView  ( the recyclerView was within the nestedscrollView). I've marked your answer as correct.

Comment: happy to help :)